# Powershell Splitting in the pipeline

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to split a list of name properties after the verb/hyphen and got it to work but I had to save to a file first.

I got it to work like this - 
Grab the Name properties and add them to a file -

```
Get-Command -Module Posh-SSH | Format-Table Name | out-file posh_ssh
```

then split list at the '-'

```
Get-Content .\posh_ssh | % {$_.split("-")[1]}
```

But is there a way to do it on one line like this?  I don't understand why this didn't work.

```
Get-Command -Module Posh-SSH | Format-Table Name |  % {$_.split("-")[1]}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Matt, I didn't realize format-table was the key to it.  Really need someplace to ask newbie questions like the difference between passthru and tee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format is a formatter cmdlet, it should never be used anywhere else than the last section of a pipeline, since it doesn't pass "true" objects on to the pipeline.
What you can do instead is to use select-object to grab the thing you want, like so (replaced module name with a module I had on my own computer):

`Get-Command -Module microsoft.powershell.management | 
select-object -expand Name |  % {$_.split("-")[1]}`

That said, for this particular question, be aware that the objects outputted by get-command are rich objects by themselves, and contain a "noun" attribute which is what I'm assuming you're ultimately after:
 
`Get-Command -Module microsoft.powershell.management | 
select-object -ExpandProperty verb`